# Using Makeappx to encrypt/copy-protect specific files UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, makeappx

I have an UWP app of which I'm creating a Appxbundle using visual studio's publish to store. Also I have seen that Makeappx is an commandline way in which we can create Appxbundle. So wantedly I explored Makeappx wherein I found that we can encrypt/copy protect specific files of an appxbundle with various parameters and available hashing algorithms using BlockMap. So went on trying to blockmap the .exe which I have seen in some of the installed apps from Windows Store which(.exe) are copy protected(cannot be copied/moved to any other location) from ProgramFiles/WindowsApps/ folder, but failed to achieve it. So it would be great if someone can guide me on how to achieve this.

**When installed an app using the appxbundle/sideload the application, the attached image which has a lock symbol on its .exe and DLL is what I'm trying to achieve.**
[image]

**Things Which I have done:**

I did [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool) this and tried to create an appxbundle and was successful. But as mentioned was not able to get how we can make specific files of copy protected.

Thank you